# how can i upload large image of around greater than 2 mb on S3 with aws lambda function with python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using aws lambda function with python3 and trying to upload > 1mb image on s3 but unable to upload it the problem is aws lambda doesn't support multipart upload so i am uploading as base64 from json but when image is big their base64 is also big and it crosses the raw input limit of aws lambda function but in actual i can only able to upload 70 kb image nothing more than that can someone guide me how can i do that

I have already tried base64 but it gives issue in larger size than 70kb of image

Comment: Can you post your Lambda code please? A 2-3 MB file should be no issue for Lambda, even in base64.

Answer (score 1):

When you base64 encode an image it is roughly 33% bigger than the original object.

AWS claims the request size limit is 6MB but I have found that often times it is closer to 4MB.

I think what you'll want to do is use a pre-signed url to bypass lambda all together.

[Multi-part presigned url with boto3](https://sandyghai.github.io/AWS-S3-Multipart-Upload-Using-Presigned-Url/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/11/binary-data-now-supported-by-api-gateway/

Keep in mind that API Gateway has a request size limit of 10 MB. AWS Lambda has a request size limit of 6 MB.

Comment: I already know the limit but it doesn't seems to work at all is their any additional setting i should do ?